# At a loss: clicks not responding

Tags: javascript, click

Help!!  I have gone over this code so often I know I am missing something, but for the life of me, I can't seem to see the problem.
Could someone please go over the code, [link to code](https://codepen.io/DCHoward/pen/poPvXjK?editors=1111), to tell me what and where I went wrong.

Here is a snippet of the code.  I can't seem to get the items to click.

```js
function click(){
  document.getElementById('paper').onclick = playPaper;
  document.getElementById('scissor').onclick = playScissor;
  document.getElementById('rock').onclick = playRock;
}
function playRock(){
  play('rock');
}
function playScissor(){
  play('scissor');
}
function playPaper(){
  play('paper')
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] here.

Comment: I don't see any `function click(){…` in your pens

Comment: I have looked over other people's codes for the rock, paper, scissor game,  Have tried to figure out how theirs is working and mine is not.  Have gone to the W3 school for answers...but  so far, I am at a loss

Comment: Hello Cedric Cholley. I had revised the code, removed the 'function', added an Event Listener instead of onclick........ and still no results.